# Regular expression for a string between 0 to 299 followed by some combination of x and y

Tags: regex, string

My regular expression must accept any string like: *299xxy, 4xyy, 156xy, 23xxxyyy, 23xxyxyy, 0xxyy.* 
And these kind of strings are not accepted: *300xy, 400yx, 305yyyx, 444yxyxy* which is obvious because my project only allows numbers within the range **0 and 299** inclusively **followed by an x, followed by any combination of zero or more x and y, and ends with y**

So far this is what I have come up with `^[0-2][0-9]*[0-9]?$` to test the numbers 0 to 299 and if the condition of x,y is added then this is what I think should be my final answer `^[0-2][0-9]*[0-9][x-y]*?$`

But when I'm testing on https://regex101.com/r/gT8wK5/1, some combinations of the accepted strings don't give me the appropriate solution.

So could you please help me so that I can understand where I'm doing wrong in my regular expression. I'm new to regular expressions so please provide solutions or helpful links that would be understood for a beginner like me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use this regex:

```
^[0-2]?\d?\dx[xy]*y$
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/gT8wK5/1321)

Comment: Thanks. Seems like it works for anything that I input. Really appreciate it.

Comment: In my class notes though our professor has not taught anything like \d. So will it be fine if I just replace \d with [0-9] because the explanation in Regex tells us that it means any number between [0-9]?

Comment: @toto If I write my final answer as: ```^([0-2]?)([0-9]?)([0-9])(x[xy]*y)$``` with the parentheses, is it ok? Because after writing the regular expression I have to draw a NFA/DFA diagram for it which can be done only if I create columns for expressions in (), in my case I would have 4 columns with its respective NFA/DFA diagram for each.

Comment: @ash_k123: Yes, it's OK. The only thing is capture groups are consuming CPU ressource. It's not a problem for a simple example as your but if it have to run million times it becomes problematic.The general case is “avoid useless capture groups”

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that the number cannot have leading zeroes since there is none in your example, which made it complicated

```
\b((?:(?:[12]\d\d)|(?:[1-9]\d)|\d)x[xy]*y)
```

Although not as complicated as it first seems. https://regex101.com/r/gT8wK5/1322

Comment: Thanks, looks complicated and difficult to understand but works for almost anything that I input.